# React, can't access updated value of state variable inside function passed to setInterval() in useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, use-effect, use-state

I am building a simple clock app with React. Currently the `countDown()` function works, but I would like the user to be able to stop/start the clock by pressing a button. I have a state boolean called `paused` that is inverted when the user clicks a button. The trouble is that after the value of `paused` is inverted, the reference to `paused` inside the `countDown()` function passed to `setInterval()` seems to be accessing the default value of `paused`, instead of the updated value.

```
function Clock(){
  const [sec, setSecs] = useState(sessionLength * 60);
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);
 
  const playPause = () => {
    setPaused(paused => !paused);
  };
  
  const countDown = () => {
    if(!paused){
        setSecs(sec => sec - 1)
      }
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        countDown();
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of calls to `setState()` in React, and/or the nature of scoping/context when using regular expressions. However I haven't been able to determine what is going on by reading documentation related to these concepts.

I can think of some workarounds that would allow my app to function as desired. However I want to understand what is wrong with my current approach. I would appreciate any light anyone can shed on this!

Comment: Try using `useCallback`?

Comment: In your code, the `useEffect` is called only once when mounting the component. The countdown function registered inside will have its initial value at the time when the `useEffect/setInterval` is called. So `paused` will only have the value when you initially mount the component.  Because you are not calling `countDown` directly or updating its value inside your useEffect, it is not updated.

Comment: @Phil setStartTime() is part of some workaround code that I meant to remove, I will fix that.

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff what confuses me about this is that setInterval() is called every second, and is successfully updating the `sec` variable each time. What I don't understand is why the current value of the boolean `paused` isn't accessed.

Comment: `setInterval` is called only one! You want only one timer at once to be running (in your use case at least). On the contrary the function you call inside, here `countDown`, is called every interval (1000ms in your exemple)

Comment: Because you define `countDown` in the component body, every time your component re-renders, that function is re-defined. The one captured in `setInterval()` is from the first render which also captures the first `paused` state value. Basically a very nuanced example of the complexity involved in React's render cycle. This is a really good question to have on StackOverflow

Comment: Here's a contrived but hopefully understandable simplified example ~ https://jsfiddle.net/vbcw08qp/

Comment: Thank you, that does clarify what is happening and the example is helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the `useEffect` is called only once when mounting the component.

The countdown function registered inside will have its initial value at the time when the `useEffect/setInterval` is called. So `paused` will only have the value when you initially mount the component. Because you are not calling countDown directly or updating its value inside your `useEffect`, it is not updated.

I think you could solve this issue like this:

```
  interval.current = useRef(null);
  const countDown = () => {
    if(!paused){
        setSecs(sec => sec - 1)
      }
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    clearInterval(interval.current);
    interval.current = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
    };
  }, [paused]);
```

your `useEffect` is dependent on the value of `paused` as it needs to create a new interval (with a different countdown function). This will trigger the `useEffect` not only on mount but every time `paused` changes. So one solution would be to clear the interval and start a new one with a different callback function.

*Edit*: You could actually improve it as you only want the interval to be running if the countDown function actually does something so this should work too:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    clearInterval(interval.current);
    if(!paused) {
      interval.current = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
    }
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
    };
  }, [paused]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Forgive me but I'm still slightly unclear on why it's necessary. I understand that without this code,  the value of `paused` is only evaluated when `useEffect()` is called, and I understand how this code fixes the problem by calling useEffect and passing an updated function each time `paused` changes. I'm still a bit confused about why the value of `paused` is only evaluated when `useEffect`  is called, and not every time `countDown` executes.

Comment: So, React re-renders a component every time a prop or state changes. But the useEffect with empty array for dependency triggers the function declared as first argument only on the first render. At that time paused is false. And even if the function countDown is recreated every render, the function inside useEffect is not. So the value of countDown inside that useEffect is actually the one that was read at the time of the initial render. Hopefully this make sense?

Comment: It can be confusing because it might look like setInterval is called every second with a new countDown function but it is not. It is only called once and will trigger the function passed as first argument for every interval but with the value defined at the moment when setInterval is called.

Comment: Yes, thank you I think I understand now. This, combined with the comments above (on the question) cleared it up for me. I think part of my confusion was that I wasn't aware that what allows the state variables to stay updated is the re-rendering of the component - I was imagining that any time the value changed, any references to it would be notified.