# How to use setinterval correctly in React

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

Why does the count increase by two each time using setinterval in react,The React version is 18

```
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count => count + 1)
    }, 1000)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>{count}</div>
  )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, can't access updated value of state variable inside function passed to setInterval() in useEffect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72252967/react-cant-access-updated-value-of-state-variable-inside-function-passed-to-se)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar)

Answer (score 2):

You want to clean up the interval.

You might be seeing it triggered twice because react mounts your component twice in debug mode to show you these kind of errors.

```
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count => count + 1)
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)

  }, [])

  return (
    <div>{count}</div>
  )
```